# Problematic Parallel Distributive Processing using Python Libraries or any language

Tags: python, arduino, robotics, pdp

I've been sitting on this idea of working on a "networked intelligence" to look into some interesting ideas on the nature of intelligence and computers. I've decided to go about doing this by designing small robotic agents that will utilize PDP across some medium, (i.e. wifi/IR or something, to be decided), to enable them to gather large quantities of data independently and then be able to process and find trends in data efficiently by utilizing them together as a "supercomputer" (I always think it's odd using that term, but it's apt, one is utilizing multiple independent processing units in unison). I'm aware that Python has some PDP libraries available, and I was hoping to program the robots onto little Arduinos, and I've got a strong idea of how to do every component of the system except for actually implementing the PDP architecture across the system.

---

**TL;DR**? I want to make a bunch of little robots that can essentially connect together to form a small supercomputer and share and amalgamate information across all the agents. Is it feasible to create a PDP program that will freely relinquish parts of its processing power and then add in new ones.

I'm a pretty strong programmer, so if it's a matter of complexity and time, I'm willing to apply myself, but if it's an issue of having to strip apart some BIOS software and writing in Assembly, then I'd rather not. I'm not as familiar with PDP ideas as I would like to, and if you have any recommended reading to get me started, much appreciated.

*Another note*, the languages or platform is completely up for changes, I'd just like to see concrete evidence that one is better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea, remins me on [sensor networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_sensor_network).

You may find that an ardunio is a little underpowered for what you want. Perhaps it would be more efficient and easier to send the data back to a PC for processing.

If you want to continue with the ardunio idea, you could implement [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) which is a fairly simple construct that allows you to write distributed programs very easily.

I have a write up on the [basics of MapReduce](http://stephenholiday.com/articles/2011/introduction-to-mapreduce/).

There is the famous [Haddop implementation](http://hadoop.apache.org/) as well as [Disco](http://discoproject.org/) (python/erlang) and a very simple shell implementation called [BashReduce](https://github.com/erikfrey/bashreduce) that Last.fm created.